# Obtaining regression model B-values in an OLS model in R

Tags: r, regression

I have the following regression model:

```
> print(summary(step1))

Call:
lm(formula = model1, data = newdat1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.66219 -0.00725 -0.00725 -0.00725  1.28056 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.15116    0.05622   2.689  0.00778 ** 
i8           0.18362    0.07986   2.299  0.02253 *  
i7           0.01749    0.08089   0.216  0.82903    
i6           0.51675    0.06042   8.553 3.27e-15 ***
i5           0.13824    0.06254   2.210  0.02823 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3131 on 198 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7797,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7753 
F-statistic: 175.2 on 4 and 198 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I am attempting to obtain the B-values of the regression (not the betas), which of these values are the B's?  If they are not found in the model how are they obtained?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the *unstandardized* regression coefficients $B$, as opposed to the standardized regression coeffecients $\beta$, then the values you provided are $B$ unless you altered the output somehow.

If you want only these numbers, you can directly print the coefficients of `step1`:

`coef <- step1$coefficients`

Each of these numbers represents the increase in your outcome variable associated with a one unit increase in your explanatory variable `i5` through `i8`.

See [here](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/multregr.html) and many many other places for a good introduction to regression in `R`.

Comment: Yes but which of columns contain these values?  Which column?  Specifically is it estimate or standard error?

Comment: @costebk08 It's the `estimate` column.  The standard error is a different metric used to assess the variability of the estimate.

Comment: @costebk08 My pleasure, have a great day.